# SDA/SCL values of accelerator VALUES get affected when I use other pins

Tags: gpio, i2c

Essentially the SDA/SCL reads the I2C values of the accelerometer perfectly fine when no other pin on the pi is active.

I have connected 4 drone propellers and whenever I give thrust to them by writing values to their pins (which have nothing to do with the SDA/SCL pins) for some reason the Gx/Gy values of the accelerometer get affected.

The values seem to have regular spikes in both positive and negative the more I increase the thrust values of the propellers.

I do not think this is a code related issue and more like electronic but just in case here is all the code:

**- Main:** https://github.com/bkstephen/drone_project_in_python/blob/master/droneLogic.py

**- Gyro output:** https://github.com/bkstephen/drone_project_in_python/blob/master/gyro.py

Comment: Hi @Stefanos, Nice to meet you again! (1) Your comment: "SDA/SCL reading I2C values of accelerometer" is a bit confusing. I would say it this way: "The I2C interfaced accelerometer's readings Gx, Gy"....

Comment: (2)  Your comment: "Accelero working perfect if other GPIO pins not 'active'" is a bit confusing for the following reason: If you set a GPIO pin to output mode, it is always 'active" because it always output either High level signal (3V+), or Low level signal (1V-). So I would say something like this: If one or more GPIO pin is set to output mode, and sending out logical levels High level or Low lever', ...

Comment: (3) Let me describe your problem in more details. (a) I first setup and read the I2C interfaced accelerometer readings Gx, Gy with any problem. (b) Then I connect, say, 4 Rpi GPIO pins to input, say, PWM signal to 4 propeller controllers to adjust thrust. (c) NOW PROBLEM: if I change GPIO pin signal, say PWM duty cycle, then accelerometer readings are no longer stable, say, with some intermittently, unreasonably higher or lower than moving average readings, ....

Comment: (4)  Let me know if I understanding your problem correctly. If not, please correct me, before I move on. Ah I need to leave now to meet a friend for Saturday brunch. See you later. Cheers.

Comment: Could you add some sample output including spikes to your question.

Comment: @tlfong01 I found a quite unorthodox solution, for now, I use an Arduino to control the actual propellers and I use the pi to read the accelerometer and set the thurst of the propellers by interfacing it with the Arduino. It is not great but it seems to solve the problem.

Comment: Oh really, that is a good experimental results. I am playing another accelero ADXL345. I found the readings not stable at all. You might liek to compare and contrast my readings listed at the very top of this penzu experiment notes. https://penzu.com/p/926a24f6. I am thinking of a couple of ways to "filter" away the bad readings, including: (1) take 5 readings moving average, and discard any new read more that 50% than the moving average, (2) Use optical isolator to reduce the noise or spikes caused by back EMF or EMI,

Comment: (3) lower I2C frequency, (4) step up Rpi 3V3 logic level to 5V0, (5) discard the readings immediately after you change the PWM duty cycle,(6) increase g range, so make the accelero not so sensitive, (7) Use PSI instead of I2C (ADXL can do either SPI or I2C, and I tried both working, but no detailed comparison yet). My experience is that SPI is less affected by noise/spikes etc than I2C.. Just brain storming, should have a couple of more get arounds I forgot.